# Merge dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df as follows:

[image: df = [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

I would like to convert it in the following way.

[image]

How do I go about it?
All help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a DataFrame for each `class_id` then [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) on `axis=1`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'student_id': [1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'class_id': [1, 2, 3, 1],
                   'teacher': ['rex', 'fred', 'hulio', 'ross']})

# Generate DF for each class_id
dfs = tuple(df[df['class_id'].eq(c_id)].reset_index(drop=True)
            for c_id in df['class_id'].unique())

# concat on axis 1
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# For Display
print(new_df.fillna('').to_string(index=False))
```

`new_df`:

```
student_id class_id teacher student_id class_id teacher student_id class_id teacher
         1        1     rex        1.0      2.0    fred        1.0      3.0   hulio
         2        1    ross
```